# how can I use google app engine with an application in phonegap

Tags: google-app-engine, cordova, google-cloud-storage

I have been developing a Phonegap client application, I need to create a web service that storage all the data that i will be sending through the app.

I want to use google app engine to create the database and the web service.

I have read a lot, but i don't find a concrete example of how to do it and how to call the web service then from the application with phonegap.

Anyone have an example of how to do this?

Comment: if you can work out how to do a HTTP POST in phonegap then the rest should be relatively simple.

Comment: Hi @PaulCollingwood yes i can work with HTTP POST using ajax. But any idea of how to develop the web service? thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/) with your app:

> Google Cloud Endpoints consists of tools, libraries and capabilities
>   that allow you to generate APIs and client libraries from an App
>   Engine application, referred to as an API backend, to simplify client
>   access to data from other applications. Endpoints makes it easier to
>   create a web backend for web clients and mobile clients such as
>   Android or Apple's iOS.
>
> For mobile developers, Endpoints provides a simple way to develop a
>   shared web backend and also provides critical infrastructures, such as
>   OAuth 2.0 authentication, eliminating a great deal of work that would
>   otherwise be needed. Furthermore, because the API backend is an App
>   Engine app, the mobile developer can use all of the services and
>   features available in App Engine, such as Datastore, Google Cloud
>   Storage, Mail, Url Fetch, Task Queues, and so forth. And finally, by
>   using App Engine for the backend, developers are freed from system
>   admin work, load balancing, scaling, and server maintenance.
>
> It is possible to create mobile clients for App Engine backends
>   without Endpoints. However, using Endpoints makes this process easier
>   because it frees you from having to write wrappers to handle
>   communication with App Engine. The client libraries generated by
>   Endpoints allow you to simply make direct API calls.
>
> Available in Python | Java

Comment: Thanks @Andrei Volgin! this is the way

Comment: Google has deprecated its v1 Endpoints library. You should use the new Google JavaScript client library instead. You can find more informatión here: cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/consume_js

Answer (score 1):

we have done similar thing for our Cordova/ionic based application. Its very simple and straight forward  using javascript client of google cloud endpoint.

Comment: Thanks @pankajanand18. I accomplish to develop the api with cloud endpoints. Now i have this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26810838/how-integrate-google-app-endpoints-with-a-phonegap-app , Could you please check it?

Comment: answered your question.